# doing xml replace operations in logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

**How do we replace strings within an XML payload in logic apps?**

**input**

```
<root>
  <alexIsAwesome>yes he is</alexIsAwesome>
  <bytes>sdfsdfjijOIJOISJDFQPWORPJkjsdlfkjlksdf==</bytes>
  <bytes>SFSDFsdfsdgfjgjkfjsdlfkjlksdf==</bytes>
</root>
```

**desired result**

```
<root>
  <alexIsAwesome>yes he is</alexIsAwesome>
  <bytes>replacetext1</bytes>
  <bytes>replacetext2</bytes>
</root>
```

**How do we iterate through XML and replace text within nodes? Please keep in mind that the input  node might be 100mb in size!**

Answer (score 3):

If you already loading the XML content in you Logic App, you could just use the [`replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#replace) function. Note that there are certain [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#throughput-limits) that you may end up hitting on successive runs.

If you have more complex use cases, you could instead try one of the following

***For payloads up to 50MB***, you could simply use the new [inline code feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code) to perform the transformations you need. You would have to convert the payload to JSON first (using [`json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#json)) and then back to XML after (using [`xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#xml)).

***But for much bigger payloads and/or more complex transformations***, it would be best to offload this to a [Function called from Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions).

The best approach here would be to store the payload in Azure Blob Storage and your function would have a [Blob Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input) and [Blob Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output) binding.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an Integration account with the Transform XML action, by pointing to a defined Map, either XSLT or Liquid type. [logic apps enterprise integration maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-maps)

Comment: would love to see an example of `liquid type`

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Sorry, I have not tried but it yet, I plan to use it myself in an upcoming project. Here is the link to the Azure documentation, the examples look fairly straight forward: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform